# How does measurement change the effective transformation matrix?

Tags: qiskit, measurement, hadamard

I have simulated three cases in Qiskit and tried doing some manual calculations to verify the simulated results.

**Case 1:**

[image: case1]

The initial state is $\psi_i = |00\rangle = \begin{Bmatrix}1 \\0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{Bmatrix}$ and the transformation is $H_2 = H_1 \otimes H_1 = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 &1 &1 \\1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.
Therefore, the final state would be $\psi_f = \frac{1}{2} \begin{Bmatrix}1 \\1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{Bmatrix}$.

This is matching with the simulation results.

---

**Case 2:**

[image: case2]

Since the first qubit is being measured, the state of first cubit collapses to $|0\rangle$, and the second qubit undergoes Hadamard transformation, the effective transformation could be $H_1\otimes \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. Therefore, the final state could be $\psi_f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{Bmatrix}1 \\0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{Bmatrix}$.

This also is matching with the simulation results.

---

**Case 3:**

[image: case3]

Since the first qubit is being measured, the state of first cubit collapses to $|0\rangle$, and the second qubit undergoes Hadamard transformation, the effective transformation could be $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\otimes \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. Therefore, by following the same method, the final state should be $\psi_f = \begin{Bmatrix}1 \\0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{Bmatrix}$. This is differing from the simulation results. The simulation is giving the final state to be $\psi_f = \begin{Bmatrix}0 \\0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{Bmatrix}$. And the effective transformation matrix from the simulation seems to be $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, which is diffrent from the transformation matrix that I calculated.

Exactly where am I doing mistake in my calculations? And what is the correct method to find the effective transformation matrix of a system that involves post-measurement? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$ H \otimes H = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \otimes  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\ 1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\ 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  $$
and therefore
$$(H \otimes H) |0\rangle^{\otimes 2} = H|0\rangle \otimes H|0\rangle = \dfrac{|0\rangle + |1 \rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \otimes \dfrac{|0\rangle + |1 \rangle}{\sqrt{2}} = \dfrac{|00\rangle + |01\rangle + |10\rangle + |11\rangle}{2} =\dfrac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix}$$
And the circuit

[image]

represents the operation $(H \otimes H) |0\rangle^{\otimes 2}$ and thus the final state **before** measurement is $|\psi\rangle = \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix} $

Upon measurement, you have even probability of $1/4$ or $25\%$ to collapse to either the state $|00\rangle$, $|01\rangle$, $|10\rangle$ or $|11\rangle$. So if you do 1000 measurements, about 1/4 of the time you will observe the state $|00\rangle$, about 1/4 of the time you will see $|01\rangle$, and so on.

You can perform a qasm (shot based) simulation and check the counts to see this effect:

You can also perform a qasm simulation and check the counts to see this: Simply do

```
from qiskit import IBMQ, Aer, QuantumCircuit, execute
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h([0,1])
qc.measure_all()
job = execute(qc, Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), shots=4321)
print('States observed upon measurement:', job.result().get_counts())

States observed upon measurement: {'10': 1112, '00': 1074, '11': 1114, '01': 1021}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to write the answer, but my issue seems to be still unsolved because, upon measurement the Qiskit simulation is giving a 100% probability of |10⟩ instead of 25% probability for each of the four states. Before measurement, it is giving 25% probability to all the four states, which is the Case 1 in my question, but upon measurement of both the states it is giving a 100% probability of |10⟩ which is what i couldn't understand why/how.

Comment: I think it might have something to do with how the matrices are changed based on measurement. For example, if there is a measuring device by which the state can be captured, the Quantum superposition collapses to a definite state, whether the measurement is made before transformation or after transformation, and it seems that that might be somehow playing a role here.

Comment: No, it has to due with the Quantum composer default collapsing to certain state in these situation because of a fixed random seed that has been set. But if you look at the probability distribution, you will see the 25% I am talking about. You can also remove the *measurement operations* and see that the state is uniformly distributed over the computational basis $\{00, 01, 10, 11\}$ as well. Check the updated answer: I added the script to perform a qasm simulation to help you visualize this.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yeah, i recently figured it out, but thanks for explaining. I am still wondering why it is always collapsing to that particular state in Qiskit, rather than any other particular state.

Comment: @SuneeshJacob it is collapsing to that particular state because Qiskit uses a pseudo-random process controlled by the visualization seed to determine to which state it will collapse. It just turns out that the seed the simulator was using at that time made it collapse to that particular state. Change the seed and you'll see it collapses to other states.

Comment: @epelaaez i just changed the seeds and it got changed, and i now understand why it works that way. thank you! (Btw i already +1'd your answer)

Answer (score 2):

In the IBMQ composer, adding a measurement collapses the qubits. If you change the *visualizations seed* (in the top right of the interface), you'll see that the final state will collapse to a state other than $|10\rangle$. When running your circuit in an actual device or simulator, you'll get the equal probability of $25\%$ that you are expecting ($\pm$ some noise if you are using a real device/noisy simulator).